# Mandar url por get y abrir modal

Tags: php, modal, url, get

tengo la siguiente duda y es saber como puedo mandar un dato por GET a la URL y abrir un modal a la vez, las modificaciones son en un "index.php" lo que busco hacer es lo siguiente, es mandar ese dato por URL para despues en el modal hacer una consulta en MYSQL con esos datos del URL, ya se que puede llegar a ser inseguro, pero en este caso no hay problema.

```
echo "<a href='#?Line=".$row["linea"]."'>";
echo "<h4 class='xp-counter text-".$TextColorSMT."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'>".$TotalProduction."%</h4>";
echo "</a>";
echo "<p class='mb-0 text-muted'><span class='badge badge-".$TextColorSMT."'>".$row["linea"]."</span><p></p>";
```

Esto da como resultado lo siguiente:

http://URL.com/Subdirectorio/#?Line=Linea%2006

Y de esta manera no me funciona necesito que sea lo siguiente:

http://URL.com/Subdirectorio/index.php?Line=Linea%2006

Por que de la primera manera me da error en la consulta una vez abierto el modal, pero de la segunda manera si funciona y es lo que quiero lograr, sin mas por el momento quedo a sus respuestas, gracias.

**Anexo que si yo pongo la liga asi en PHP:**

http://URL.com/Subdirectorio/index.php?Line=Linea%2006

La pagina trata de abrir el modal pero al instante se recarga y no alcanza abrir el modal, el dato queda en la URL pero el modal no abre debido a que la pagina recarga.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mediante una llamada **AJAX**, mandas el parámetro que necesites y en el `success` (que ocurre si todo ha ido bien) entonces abres la modal. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Mediante una redirección, como estás haciendo, no podrías hacerlo.

Comment: Con el uso de Ajax ni siquiera haría falta un modal, ya que podrías actualizar el contenido mismo de la página. Es una visión interesante desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario, donde una página podría hacer las veces de un contenedor general, sin necesidad de tantas ventanas flotantes por aquí y por allá, con el consumo de recursos que eso pudiera suponer. Además, es mucho más cómodo y agradable para el usuario. Yo no usaría un modal jamás en una aplicación, gracias a que Ajax existe. En mi opinión, los modales son de la época de Windows 3, hoy día tienen poco sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo entiendo y pues creo que tienes razon, pero por necesidades lo que necesito ahora es un modal

Comment: Respeto que por algún motivo **tengas que usar un modal**, a pesar de las complicaciones y de la mala experiencia de usuario que eso supone, pero bueno. Si el problema es que la página se recarga, puedes poner un `preventDefault()` en el código que lanza la petición para que no se recargue. Y en cuanto a la URL, veo que en el `href` tienes esto: `echo "<a href='#?Line=".$row["linea"]."'>";` por eso se está agregando un signo de `#` en la URL.  De todos modos, todo esto lo puedes recoger por Javascript y simplificar.